# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) at eval (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm being thrown an Uncaught SyntaxError message. The code worked yesterday and I can't remember changing anything.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be? I've included the Javascript and jQuery below.

```js
function updateOutput() {
  $("iframe").contents().find("html").html("<html><head><style type='text/css'>" + $("#cssPanel").val() + "</style></head><body>" + $("#htmlPanel").val() + "</body></html>");

  document.getElementById("outputPanel").contentWindow.eval($("#javascriptPanel").val());
}

$(".toggleButton").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("highlightedButton");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass("highlightedButton");
});

$(".toggleButton").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(this).removeClass("highlightedButton");
  var panelID = $(this).attr("id") + "Panel";
  $("#" + panelID).toggleClass("hidden");
  var numberOfActivePanels = 4 - $(".hidden").length;
  $(".panel").width(($(window).width() / numberOfActivePanels) - 10);
});

$(".panel").height($(window).height() - $("#nav").height() - 17);

$(".panel").width($(window).width() / 2 - 10);
updateOutput();

$("textarea").on('change keyup paste', function() {
  updateOutput();
});
```

Thank you all in advance, I'm still relatively new to programming!

Comment: The issue is due to the content of `$("#javascriptPanel").val()` which you haven't shown us. There is syntax issue in there which is throwing an error when you run it through `eval()`. ***However*** I would state that the use of `eval()` itself is a massive problem and should be avoided. Exactly how you do that depends on your use case and requirements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This looks pretty much like poor man's jsfiddle to me, where `eval` might be totally appropriate.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi Rory, thanks for the speedy response. I'm using eval as I'm still learning and that's the only function that I have been shown so far. I am aware that it isn't best practice to use it and I will be trying to rewrite my code to move away from it. I have also now found the error thanks to your reply. I was missing a "(" in my content for javascriptPanel!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Regards `eval()`, I'd suggest looking in to script injection as an alternative, here's something to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29909927/519413