# Event listeners are not working on popup window when close it's parent window

Tags: javascript, html, popup, window

I want to make my print button working on the popup window but the problem is when I close the parent window or navigate on another URL in the parent window then print button from my popup window is not working.

Event listeners are not working in the popup window may be they disappear with the parent window.

Note: It's working fine when the parent window is there

Below is the code which is I am using please help me out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new window, and assure that the new window GETS focus (send the new window to the front).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=200,height=100");
  myWindow.document.write("<p>A new window!</p>");
   var printButton = myWindow.document.createElement('BUTTON');
   var buttonNode = myWindow.document.createTextNode('PRINT');
    printButton.appendChild(buttonNode);
    myWindow.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',             printButton.outerHTML);
   var btn = myWindow.document.querySelector('button');
   btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    myWindow.window.print();
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357312/running-javascript-in-new-window-open, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909927/inject-an-opened-window-with-script, OR https://jsfiddle.net/murx2o9p/ .. I don't like my own solution though.

Comment: Works for me in Safari

Comment: @Jason also I don't like your solution.....but thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `addEventListener` rather use the `onclick` attribute so that it's persistent.

Demo: https://codepen.io/craigiswayne/pen/moYYga

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=500,height=500");
  myWindow.document.write("<p>A new window!</p>");

  var printButton = myWindow.document.createElement('BUTTON');
  printButton.innerHTML = "PRINT";
  printButton.setAttribute("onclick", "window.print()");
  myWindow.document.body.appendChild(printButton);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to open a new window, and assure that the new window GETS focus (send the new window to the front).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

The reason your way didn't work was because there was no reference to the original event handler once the parent changed.

The above code will not work on StackOverflow due to the sandboxed environment of the iframe that runs the code. So i've added the codepen link to demonstrate the solution

Comment: Hey, What if I don't want to include that print button on the print page? seems above code will not work for that scenario!

Comment: When I am clicking on the print button it shows me a print window having a print button on it so i don't want that print button on the page(on print page)

Comment: So you just want a new window no button? I'd suggest creating a new question with a description of what you're asking krishna

Comment: I want like this:                                                        
      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      btn.style.display = 'none';
      windowPopup.window.print();
      btn.style.display = 'block';
    });

Comment: Which is possible using event listener like                 btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      btn.style.display = 'none';
      windowPopup.window.print();
      btn.style.display = 'block';
    });                                                                                                                             How should achieve this through your code?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you can change the js to the following: `function myFunction() {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=500,height=500");
  myWindow.document.write("<p>A new window!</p>");
  myWindow.print();
}`

Comment: Here I want to hide button print while window.print. In event listener, this is possible because that click on event listener is asynchronous so, I can handle print button show/hide logic in that callback ex. btn.addEventListener('click', () => {                                           
    btn.style.display = 'none'; 
    myWindow.window.print();                                                     
     btn.style.display = 'block'; 
    });             using your provided solution how we can achieve it?