# Programmatically login data with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

when the page loaded "https://accounts.google.com/signin" I want to fill the inputs automatically and it remains only press enter to login. Here is my code:

```
//Reminder I have data in localStorage


let dataUser;
if (localStorage.user != null) { 
    dataUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.user);
}
else {
    dataUser = [];
}

function NavigateData(i) {

    let user     = dataUser[i].user;
    let password = dataUser[i].password;
    let Ste      = dataUser[i].title;

    window.open("https://accounts.google.com/signin/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin", "_self");

    document.getElementById('j_username').value = user; 
    document.getElementById('j_password').value = password;

}
```

[image]

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909927/inject-an-opened-window-with-script).

Comment: I want when I click on button Navigate, this is the last take data as {user1,password1} and put automaticcaly on inputs the next page.

Comment: @GUENNOU You can't do that, _by design_. Google doesn't allow it and you shouldn't even be doing this in the first place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.